# Data fetch error

Tags: error

I've been working on a SP site for sometime now but since yesterday everytime I hit the 'cog' I get the Message from webpage - 'An error has occurred with the data fetch. Please refresh the page and retry'.
I've researched it and had a suggestion to delete cookies but this has not solved the problem.
Can anybody suggest what the issue may be?
Thanks

[image: Data fetch error]

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome but I access the site thru Citrix which opens it in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I would suggest trying is enabling compatibility view settings for your site in IE.  If that doesn't work, ensure IE has your site added as intranet or a trusted site at the least.

Finally, is your citrix environment locked down in such a way that cookies are not being written from the site.  THis could also cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, I'll look into those issues. I'm just confused because I only encountered this problem yesterday after working on this site for months and I don't believe I changed anything. Thanks again.